# How to read through a csv file to find corresponding values in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read through a csv file to find the corresponding values in a dictionary. I have two csv files. I have to create a dictionary with the first csv file. Then I have to read through the other csv file to find the matching or corresponding values of the dictionary that I created with the first csv file, but I cannot create a dictionary out of the second csv file because the second csv file will have a duplicate inside of it (MAC12,4 and MAC12,2).

This is what the first csv file looks like.

```
Model #,Brand,Version
VB17,ASUS,14.0
AR51M,ALIEN WARE,15.5
MAC12,APPLE,13.7
XR55,ACER,17.1
```

This is what the second csv file looks like.

```
Model #,Quantity
MAC12,4
AR51M,3
XR55,1
MAC12,2
```

I then need to my output to display the Brand, Quantity, and Version in the order they appear in the second csv file like so:

```
APPLE: 4 13.7
ALIEN WARE: 3 15.5
ACER: 1 17.1
APPLE: 2 13.7
```

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
import csv

MODEL = 0
BRAND = 1
VERSION = 2 

def main():
    
    models = model_numbers("model.csv", MODEL)
    for i in models:
        print(i, models[i])

    with open("order.csv", ) as order_file:
        reader = csv.reader(order_file)
        next(reader)
        for key in models.keys():
            value = models[key]
            brand = value[0]
            quantity = value[1]

            print(f"{brand}: {quantity}")


def model_numbers(filename, key):

    models = {}
    with open(filename, "rt") as models_file:
        reader = csv.reader(models_file)
        next(reader)
        for key in reader:
            model = key[MODEL]
            brand_name = key[BRAND]
            version = key[VERSION]
            models[model] = [brand_name, version]
    
    return models 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what my current output looks like:

```
VB17 ['ASUS', '14.0']
AR51M ['ALIEN WARE', '15.5']
MAC12 ['APPLE', '13.7']     
XR55 ['ACER', '17.1']       
ASUS: 14.0
ALIEN WARE: 15.5
APPLE: 13.7
ACER: 17.1
```

And this is what I want.

```
VB17 ['ASUS', '14.0']
AR51M ['ALIEN WARE', '15.5']
MAC12 ['APPLE', '13.7']     
XR55 ['ACER', '17.1']
APPLE: 4 13.7
ALIEN WARE: 3 15.5
ACER: 1 17.1
APPLE: 2 13.7
```

Comment: Why is `APPLE` quantity 4, when in second file you have two MAC12: 4 and 2, which is 6?

Comment: Oh I see, you have them separate, even though they are the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try using the infromation about files and needed output you've provided:

```py
import csv

def get_model_quantity():
    models = []
    with open("file_2.csv", "r") as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=",")
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            model = row[0]
            quantity = row[1]
            models.append((model, quantity))
    return models

def get_model_information():
    info = {}
    with open("file_1.csv", "r") as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=",")
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            model = row[0]
            brand = row[1]
            version = row[2]
            info[model] = {
                "brand": brand,
                "version": version
            }
    return info


model_quantity = get_model_quantity()
model_information = get_model_information()

for model, quantity in model_quantity:
    model_info = model_information[model]
    brand = model_info["brand"]
    version = model_info["version"]
    print(f"{brand}: {quantity} {version}")
```

Output:

```
APPLE: 4 13.7
ALIEN WARE: 3 15.5
ACER: 1 17.1
APPLE: 2 13.7
```